# Livewire pagination links are missing the route

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-pagination

I created a Livewire component that uses the WithPagination trait, on the render function I paginate the results and on the component's blade I print the paginator links, the paginator works however when I click any paginator link the page URL changes to the base_url/?page=x

The component class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\Order;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class Table extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public function render()
    {
        $orders = Order::latest()->paginate(10);
        return view('livewire.table', compact(['orders']));
    }
}
```

The component blade:

```
<div>
    @foreach($orders as $order)
        {{ $order->name }}
    @endforeach
    {{ $orders->links() }}
</div>
```

I tried the appends (like in regular Laravel paginator) and the withQueryString but when I click any pagination link the URL changes to the base URL only with the ?page=page_number, and for many reasons, I need to keep the original route.

Am I missing something?

Versions:
Laravel 8
Livewire 2

Comment: Please show the complete content of your `livewire.table` view file. Update your original post and do not copy into the comments here. I suspect you do not have a single root element in your template, f. ex. `<div> ... table, links, etc. ... </div>`.

Comment: @codedge I already updated the blade code, I do have a single div to contain all the component view code inside.

Comment: is this a full-page component, or a component included in your root view? can you update the question with the information of how you include this component.